# Absorbing Markov chain in a computer. Is "almost every" turned into always convergence in computer executions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, simulation, almost-everywhere

Let $\{X_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ be an absorbing Markov chain. It is well-known that
$$ P(\text{chain gets absorbed}|X_0=i)=1. $$
My question is how this is interpreted in practice. We have that for almost every "experiment" $\omega$, the chain gets absorbed. I am not sure how to interpret this "almost sure" sense. If I simulate the chain in a computer, will I **always** observe convergence to an absorbing state? Or could there be some execution $\omega$ in the computer in which the chain does not converge (because $\omega$ does not form part of "almost every $\omega$")? In practice in the computer, does "almost every" play any role?

Edit: Convergence means that, from any starting state $i$, the random walk in the computer reaches an absorbing state in a finite number (not fixed) of steps.

Comment: in practice 'anything can happen' due to round-off errors

Comment: This is quite strongly dependent on implementation. Broadly speaking a.s. statements are generally not violated in computer simulations, though one should be a bit careful to narrow the scope of that statement (consider for instance a continuous random variable for an idea of why). In an example like this you should be more concerned that the absorption might take longer than your finite truncated simulation time (which is well-defined mathematically, this is not just a computational problem).

Comment: @LinAlg I am referring to movements from node to node, not to numerical computations. Imagine three states, $A$, $B$ and $C$, with $P(X_{n+1}=A|X_n=B)=0.5$, $P(X_{n+1}=B|X_n=A)=0.5$, $P(X_{n+1}=C|X_n=A)=0.5$, $P(X_{n+1}=C|X_n=B)=0.5$ and $C$ absorbent. Could it happen that the computer moves from $A$ to $B$ and from $B$ to $A$ repeatedly up to infinity?

Comment: @Ian You said that "a.s. statements are generally not violated in computer simulations". I have executed these type of algorithms for absorbing Markov chains and have always obtained convergence (absorption in a finite number of steps)? Is it possible to not obtain convergence, that is, that a walk $\omega$ starts like a cycle in which never approaches to the absorbing state, although this has zero mathematical probability?

Comment: As I said, it depends on the internal implementation. Stochastic process examples are really the wrong place to investigate this because you must always perform a finite time sample, so there will be a positive probability that the "mathematical" chain hasn't been absorbed by the end of your simulation. A better example would be something like: I generate a random variable uniformly on $[0,1]$, I apply a function $f$ that is only defined on $(0,1]$, is it possible that the program crashes because I try to compute $f(0)$?

Comment: @Ian If I am sincere, I have no idea whether the program would crash. In principle, since the probability is $0$, would that implementation be correct?

Comment: It depends on exactly how the generator works. Because this case and the analogous case for $1$ actually come up in practice, I think most uniform generators in standard software (Matlab, Python, etc.) never return 0 or 1. This does not spoil the defining property of the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ which is $P(X \in (a,b))=b-a$ for $a<b$. In this case the program from my previous comment would not crash. But if somehow $f$ were constructed to be undefined at some intermediate point, I wouldn't be surprised to see the program crash after many trials.

Comment: @Ian So, and this is my last question, I promise: I read an article in which the goal was to prove the always convergence of a computer algorithm. Using probability tools, the authors proved that the number of steps is finite a.s. Is this a valid proof for "always convergence"?

Comment: Just finite a.s. is exactly the same stochastic process issue from before. A uniform bound proven to hold a.s. would convert the situation to what we've been talking about just now.

Answer (score 1):

If you're taking about a simulation where you keep choosing between the possible next transitions using the output of a PRNG (pseudo-random number generator), then there has to be exceptions.

We can even construct fairly small Markov chains that are *mathematically* impeccably absorbing but where the PRNG will *never* reach the absorbing state no natter how you seed it.

Suppose your PRNG has an internal state of $n$ bits. Then let our Markov chain have states $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n+1\}$ states, where state $n+1$ is absorbing and every other state $k$ moves to $0$ or $k+1$ with equal probability.

Then, starting in state $0$, your simulation can only reach the absorbing state if the PRNG produces $n+1$ "go right" in a row. That is still *possible*, though.

However, note that there are only at most $2^n$ different sequences of "left" and "right" that *can possibly* be the outcome of the next $n+1$ draws of the PRNG -- because that's how many different internal states it has. So, if we know the PRNG we can choose the description or the Markov chain such that the sequence it needs to get to the absorbing state is one of the $2^{n+1}-2^n$ sequences that the PRNG *cannot* produce.

And then, no matter how long you keep simulating the chain, it will never reach the absorbing state.

But *matematically*, the chain always has finite probability at least $2^{-(n+1)}$ of ending up in the absorbing state within the next $n+1$ moves, so this ought to happen *eventually* with probability $1$.

Comment: Where'd the $2n$ come from?

Comment: @Ian: Sloppy editing, now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your bigger issue is not so much the computer (as pointed out in the comments), but convergence, which is a statement for "large n"

In particular how are you measuring convergence? Are you just checking at some time $n$ whether it has been absorbed? In which case, there is a positive probability that it will never be absorbed. (Think of a simple chain that starts from state 1, has a probability of 0.00001 of staying at 1, or going to 0 otherwise, which is an absorbing state). For any finite n, the probability that you are still in state 1 is $(0.00001)^N$, which is indeed greater than 0.

Comment: Paragraphs 1 and 2 describe precisely what is happening; but I am not sure paragraphs 3 and 4 bring anything to the answer.

Comment: @E-A For convergence, I mean being absorbed in a finite number of steps, see the edit. In your example, the probability that the chain remains at $1$ up to infinity is $0$. So, could it happen in the computer that the chain comes back infinitely many times to $1$? Does this make any sense? Would not this depend on which probability $P$ we have defined?

Comment: @Did, yeah I wasn't sure where the confusion of the OP stemmed from, so figured I would add two more paragraphs; I removed it now for clarity. feel free to edit if you see something off/would like to clarify.

Comment: @user39756 In the chain I considered, the probability of the chain going from 0 to 1 is 0, so it cannot come back to 1 at all. It can, however, stay there with positive probability for any finite stopping time. The chain you constructed under your post will go to C a.s. but, for any finite time in which you check this chain, it could be in either A or B, and that does not violate this almost sure convergence.